# iPhone Development: Core-Plot performance Slow when handling a huge data

Tags: iphone, charts, core-plot

iPhone Development: Core-Plot performance slow when handling a huge data.

I tried to put 500 Data into Plot. The performance show that it is really slow.

And most of the CandleStick Chart all mix together...

Anyone has any solution for me, please?

Comment: You should use Instruments to profile the code and see where it is spending most of its time.

Answer (score 7):

1. Be aware of the size of the plot area. If you have more data points than pixels, filter the data set as @benzado suggested.
2. Use graphical elements that are fast to draw--opaque colors, no gradients, no images, no shadows. If the bars are only going to be a few pixels wide, don't set both the fill and border line; use whichever one draws faster.
3. Reduce or eliminate extraneous elements like minor tick marks and grid lines.
4. Use one of the datasource methods that provide a group of points in one call rather than one at a time.

   ```
   -(NSArray *)numbersForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange;
   -(double *)doublesForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange;
   -(CPTNumericData *)dataForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange;
   ```

Comment: For #4: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/examples/CorePlotGallery/src/plots/ColoredBarChart.m#152

Comment: thank you so much for your reply,Eric. Actually, i tried download this example project before, but when i compile it is has a lot of error(i didnt change anything), it said something not found.I am now using core-plot0.4 develop the candle stick graphic, but now the latest one is 0.9, do u think i should change to 0.9? if i change, i   have to change a lot of coding...

Comment: I would update. A lot has changed since the 0.4 release. Lots of bug fixes and some performance optimizations. You will have to make some changes in your code to make it work, though. If you want to go all the way up-to-date, pull the latest code with Mercurial. The 1.0 release is almost ready and shouldn't be too different from what's available now.

Comment: Hi, is me again. I have now change to 0.9. i am trying to use this function to help me separate the 1400 data in the graphic 

-(NSArray *)numbersForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange;

Do you have some example that make a UIScrollBar at the bottom, scroll to left to change the range of the data , then i dont have to point all 1400 data in the graphic at the same time ?

Answer (score 2):

We did some speed comparisons of iOS Charts and one of them was Core-plot. Unfortunately Core-plot was so slow it could not do the first test!!

There were other chart components which were able to handle big data much more efficiently.

The test results and test setup are here: https://www.scichart.com/ios-chart-performance-comparison

In table format the results of a comparison between four main chart iOS providers can be found here.

[image: iOS Chart Performance Comparison]

*Disclosure, I am the tech lead of the SciChart project*

Answer (score 1):

Plot a sample of your data! Don't plot all 500 data points if you don't actually need to draw them all.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Because i am doing a stock chart, so i have to put all 500 or more data into it.