# Core Plot IPad performance issue

Tags: ios, ipad, core-plot

In my app, i got core plot bar chart on a scroll view with paging, on IPhone all work fine , you page between different pages, one of them is the plot with its own touch gestures and properties.
Problem starts when i run the same code on IPad. plot becomes slow and laggy, all touch gestures takes a lot of time to response and the whole scroller paging becomes heavy and slow.
the chart itself contains 100 points or so (not so big).
I've read somewhere that the change of plot space between IPhone and IPad makes these changes in performance because the IPad renders 4 times the graphics. Did anybody had this problem before? Is there something i can do to make performance better on IPad without limit or lose preform data?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about your app. How big (in points) is the graph? Is this on a device (which one?) or the simulator? What gestures does your app use and what do they do to the graph?

Comment: the graph is 3/4 of the screen (on iPhone and on iPad), its slow on the simulator and on the iPad 2 (didn't check on other iPad devices). my app using scrollerDidScroll from scrollViewDelegate and the scrollView touch gestures. plus shouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent and shouldScaleBy from core plot

Comment: I've also bumped with this behavior on my app, currently I've solved this by limiting the amount of times that the graph is repainted...

Comment: This can be quick work around, But there must be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Core plot is a very slow library which can only handle a few hundred data-points (or less in some cases).

I wrote an answer here which describes a [performance comparison between iOS chart components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45589678/303612). One of the charts tested was core-plot and it couldn't do the first test!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the specifics of your app, here are some general performance hints:

1. Set all line styles and fills that you don't need to `nil` rather than transparent colors.
2. Use solid color fills rather than gradients or images where possible.
3. Reduce the number of axis labels, tick marks, and grid lines if possible. Perhaps eliminate minor tick marks and grid lines completely (set the corresponding line styles to `nil`).
4. Only call `-reloadData` when a significant portion of the plot data changes. Use the insert and delete methods when possible. See the "Real Time Plot" in the *Plot Gallery* example app.