# Improving Performance Of Core Plot

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, plot, core-plot

I'm plotting **Real Time ECG** using **CorePlot** library.When it uses in *iPad air* the performance is okay.But when i tried it with **iPad mini**, There is a delay in the plotting.I have done with collapseLayer and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713445/core-plot-ipad-performance-issue) also.that didn't solved my problem.Can anyone suggest new solution for this.

My code is below:

```
-(void)newData:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{

    for (int i =0;i<plotcount;i++){

        if([Qrrch0 count]>0 || [Qrrch1 count]>0 || [Qrrch2 count]>0 || [Qrrch3 count]>0 || [Qrrspo2 count]>0 ){

            if(g1==1 && thePlot){

                currentIndex ++;
            }
            if(g2==1 && thePlot1){
                currentIndex1 ++;
            }
            if(g3==1 && thePlot2){
                currentIndex2 ++;
            }
            if(g4==1 && thePlot3){
                currentIndex3 ++;
            }
            if(spo2==1 && thePlot4){
                currentIndex4 ++;
            }

            if(arrayIndex>=kchannel1-1)
            {
                arrayIndex=0;
            }

            if(arrayIndex1>=kchannel2-1)
            {
                arrayIndex1=0;
            }
            if(arrayIndex>=kchannel1-1)
            {
                arrayIndex=0;
            }
            if(arrayIndex2>=kchannel3-1)
            {
                arrayIndex2=0;
            }

            if(arrayIndex3>=kchannel4-1)
            {
                arrayIndex3=0;
            }

            if(arrayIndex4>=kchannel5-1)
            {
                arrayIndex4=0;
            }




            if(g1==1 && thePlot){
                 currentIndex5++;
                if(currentIndex5>=kchannel1)
                {
                    if(arrayIndex==0)
                    {
                        [thePlot reloadDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(arrayIndex, arrayIndex)];
                    }else{
                  [thePlot deleteDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(arrayIndex, 1)];


                    }
                }
                if([Qrrch0 count]!=0)
                {

                    arrPlot[arrayIndex]=[[Qrrch0 objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];

                    lastPlot0=[Qrrch0 objectAtIndex:0];

                }else{
                    arrPlot[arrayIndex]=[lastPlot0 integerValue];

                }
                   arrayIndex++;
            }
            if(g2==1 && thePlot1){
                currentIndex6++;
                if(currentIndex6>=kchannel2)
                {
                    if(arrayIndex1==0)
                    {
                        [thePlot1 reloadDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(arrayIndex1, arrayIndex1)];
                    }else{
                        [thePlot1 deleteDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(arrayIndex1, 1)];
                    }

                }
                if([Qrrch1 count]!=0)
                {


                    arrPlot1[arrayIndex1]=[[Qrrch1 objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];

                    lastPlot1=[Qrrch1 objectAtIndex:0];

                }else{
                    arrPlot1[arrayIndex1]=[lastPlot1 integerValue];

                }
                arrayIndex1++;

            }
            if(g3==1 && thePlot2){
                currentIndex7++;

                if(currentIndex7>=kchannel3)
                {
                    if(arrayIndex2==0)
                    {
                        [thePlot2 reloadDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(arrayIndex2, arrayIndex2)];
                    }else{
                        [thePlot2 deleteDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(arrayIndex2, 1)];
                    }

                }
                if([Qrrch2 count]!=0)
                {

                    arrPlot2[arrayIndex2]=[[Qrrch2 objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
                    lastPlot2=[Qrrch2 objectAtIndex:0];

                }else{
                    arrPlot2[arrayIndex2]=[lastPlot2 integerValue];
                                   }
                   arrayIndex2++;
            }
            if(g4==1 && thePlot3){
                currentIndex8++;

                if(currentIndex8>=kchannel4)
                {
                    if(arrayIndex3==0)
                    {
                        [thePlot3 reloadDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(arrayIndex3, arrayIndex3)];
                    }else{
                        [thePlot3 deleteDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(arrayIndex3, 1)];
                    }

                }

                if([Qrrch3 count]!=0)
                {

                    arrPlot3[arrayIndex3]=[[Qrrch3 objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
                    lastPlot3=[Qrrch3 objectAtIndex:0];

                }else{
                    arrPlot3[arrayIndex3]=[lastPlot3 integerValue];
                                   }
                arrayIndex3++;
            }
            if(spo2==1 && thePlot4){
                 currentIndex9++;
                if(currentIndex9>=kchannel5)
                {
                    if(arrayIndex4==0)
                    {
                        [thePlot4 reloadDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(arrayIndex4, arrayIndex4)];
                    }else{
                        [thePlot4 deleteDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(arrayIndex4, 1)];
                    }

                }
                if([Qrrspo2 count]!=0)
                {

                    arrPlot4[arrayIndex4]=[[Qrrspo2 objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];

                    lastPlot4=[Qrrspo2 objectAtIndex:0];

                }else{
                    arrPlot4[arrayIndex4]=[lastPlot4 integerValue];


                }
                arrayIndex4++;
            }

            if(g1==1 && thePlot){
                if([Qrrch0 count]!=0)
                {
                    [Qrrch0 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                }
                if(currentIndex>=kchannel1)
                {
                currentIndex=1;
                                     }
                   [thePlot   insertDataAtIndex:currentIndex-1 numberOfRecords:1];
            }
            if(g2==1 && thePlot1){
                if([Qrrch1 count]!=0)
                {
                    [Qrrch1 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                }

                if(currentIndex1>=kchannel2)
                {
                    currentIndex1=1;

                }
                    [thePlot1   insertDataAtIndex:currentIndex1-1 numberOfRecords:1];
                }
            if(g3==1 && thePlot2){

                if([Qrrch2 count]!=0)
                {
                    [Qrrch2 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                }
                if(currentIndex2>=kchannel3)
                {
                    currentIndex2=1;
            }
                    [thePlot2   insertDataAtIndex:currentIndex2-1 numberOfRecords:1];
            }

            if(g4==1 && thePlot3){
                if([Qrrch3 count]!=0)
                {
                    [Qrrch3 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                }
                if(currentIndex3>=kchannel4)
                {
                    currentIndex3=1;
                }
                [thePlot3   insertDataAtIndex:currentIndex3-1 numberOfRecords:1];

            }

            if(spo2==1 && thePlot4){
                if([Qrrspo2 count]!=0)
                {
                    [Qrrspo2 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                }
                if(currentIndex4>=kchannel5)
                {
                    currentIndex4=1;
                }
                [thePlot4   insertDataAtIndex:currentIndex4-1 numberOfRecords:1];

            }

                   }
        else
        {

            [self datacha];


        }
    }

}


-(void) datacha{
    NSArray *array;
    if([FinalArray count]>0){

        if(g1==1 && thePlot){
            array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[FinalArray objectAtIndex:0]];
            [Qrrch0 addObjectsFromArray:array];
        }
        if(g1==1 && thePlot){
            [FinalArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
    if([FinalArray1 count]>0){
        if(g2==1 && thePlot1){
            array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[FinalArray1 objectAtIndex:0]];
            [Qrrch1 addObjectsFromArray:array];
        }
        if(g2==1 && thePlot1){
            [FinalArray1 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
    if([FinalArray2 count]>0){
        if(g3==1 && thePlot2){

            array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[FinalArray2 objectAtIndex:0]];
            [Qrrch2 addObjectsFromArray:array];
        }
        if(g3==1 && thePlot2){
            [FinalArray2 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        }
    } if([FinalArray3 count]>0){
        if(g4==1 && thePlot3){
            array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[FinalArray3 objectAtIndex:0]];
            [Qrrch3 addObjectsFromArray:array];
        }
        if(g4==1 && thePlot3){
            [FinalArray3 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
    if([FinalArray4 count]>0){
        if(spo2==1 && thePlot4){
            array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[FinalArray4 objectAtIndex:0]];
            [Qrrspo2 addObjectsFromArray:array];
        }
        if(spo2==1 && thePlot4){
            [FinalArray4 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Plot Data Source Methods


-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{

    if(plot == thePlot)
    {
        if(currentIndex5>=kchannel1)
        {
            return kchannel1;
        }else{
        return currentIndex5;
        }
    }

    if(plot == thePlot1)
    {
        if(currentIndex6>=kchannel2)
        {
            return kchannel2;
        }else{
            return currentIndex6;
        }
    }

    if(plot == thePlot2)
    {
        if(currentIndex7>=kchannel3)
        {
            return kchannel3;
        }else{
            return currentIndex7;
        }
    }

    if(plot == thePlot3)
    {
        if(currentIndex8>=kchannel4)
        {
            return kchannel4;
        }else{
            return currentIndex8;
        }
    }

    if(plot == thePlot4)
    {
        if(currentIndex9>=kchannel5)
        {
            return kchannel5;
        }else{
            return currentIndex9;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}



-(double)doubleForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx{

    double num;

    NSString *textval = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", countofpktloss];
    self.losscount.text = textval;

    switch ( fieldEnum ) {

        case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
            if(plot == thePlot){
                num =currentIndex;
            }
                        else if(plot == thePlot1)
                        {

                            num = currentIndex1;

                        }
                        else if(plot == thePlot2)
                        {

                            num = currentIndex2;

                        }
                        else if(plot == thePlot3)
                        {

                            num = currentIndex3;

                        }

                        else if(plot == thePlot4)
                        {

                            num = currentIndex4;

                        }

            break;

        case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
            if(plot == thePlot){

                num =arrPlot[idx];

            }

                        else
                    if(plot == thePlot1){

                        num =arrPlot1[idx];


                        }
                        else if(plot == thePlot2){

                            num =arrPlot2[idx];


                        }
                        else if(plot == thePlot3)
                        {
                            num =arrPlot3[idx];


                        }

                        else if(plot == thePlot4)
                        {
                             num =arrPlot4[idx];

                        }

            break;

        default:
            break;

    }

    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `collapsesLayers` property is there to help save memory for a static graph. Using it on a graph that updates frequently makes the performance worse since it requires the graph to redraw everything, not just the part that changed, e.g., the plot.

---

*Added comments*

1. Make sure the timer stops when you expect it to. Otherwise, it will keep adding points to the plots.
2. How often does the timer fire to add points to the plots? There's no point in updating the plots more than 60 times per second and you may need to reduce that further on older devices like the iPad 2 to get good performance with lots of data points. You can add more than one point in each update if needed.
3. Check the ranges used to reload data points. You're passing the same number as the location and length of the range. I suspect you mean to use a length of one (1) for each range. If so, you're reloading more data than required on each pass.

Comment: When `collapsesLayers =NO` CPU usage is low.But plot is delayed.
When `collapsesLayers =YES` CPU usage is bit high but no delay for plotting.

Comment: Where does the delay happen?

Comment: Even when i stop input to the graph,The graph keeps plotting.Before that the plot immediately stops when the input stops.

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. Can you post your code to help us see what's going on?

Comment: Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at other chart libraries? SciChart provides an iOS chart tailored for realtime ECG applications. It's extremely fast and doesn't have the performance problems of Core plot.

- See [iOS Chart Performance Comparison](https://www.scichart.com/ios-chart-performance-comparison/)
- and [SciChart iOS ECG demo](https://www.scichart.com/example/ios-ecg-monitor-chart-demo/)

*Disclosure, I am the tech lead on the scichart projects*